# How do I test an AngularJS service applies a CSS class using angular.element("element").addClass using Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

We are working on a dark mode theme for our app, we set this via changing the CSS class on a body element. It is toggled on and off through an AngularJS service with a call like...

```
function setTheme(theme){
    angular.element("body").addClass(theme);
}
```

I am trying to write unit tests using Jasmine in the service to ensure `angular.element("body")` is called with adding the theme CSS class such like....

```
this.mockAngularElement = {
    addClass: jasmine.createSpy("addClass"),
    removeClass: jasmine.createSpy("removeClass")
};
jasmine.createSpy(angular, "element").and.returnValue(this.mockAngularElement);
```

And where the respective unit tests have these two expect lines...

```
expect(angular.element).toHaveBeenCalledWith("body");
        expect(this.mockAngularElement.addClass).toHaveBeenCalledWith("mock-theme");
```

However jasmine seems to complain something on the lines of...

```
Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
        Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments) in node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 3690)
        <REDACTED>.spec.js:153:53
```

Any ideas on this? Whats a better way to actual test the body element is getting this CSS class applied from this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the toHaveClass syntax of Jasmine.

```
expect(angular.element("body")).toHaveClass("css-class");
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, we can check Angular element is called with...

`spyOn(angular, "element").and.callThrough();`

and check using standard `expect()`

Can't test `addClass` and `removeClass` though, as mocking angular element can break the app when unit testing with some odd angular errors.

This should probably be good enough for our test cases.